# Сделать лямбду которая возвращает длину массива, созданного из текста разделенного пробелами

Tags: java

Учусь, делаю домашнее задание. Учим лямбды и вроде все понятно было до этого задания. Вот условия на английском:

> Add another method, which accepts String and  Function<String,
> Integer> (accepts String returns Integer.) And make lambda which count
> of words in String (split by space to array of string, and get array
> length)

Вот пару моих вариантов которые не работают, уже перепробовал все что было в голове, помогите((

```
String text3 = "We have to count words of this text";

public static Integer convertStringToInt(String string, Function<String, Integer> function){
    return function.apply(string);

}

convertStringToInt(text3, String.valueOf(text3.split(" ")) -> Array.getLength(text3));
convertStringToInt(text3, String.valueOf(text3.split(" ")) :: length);
convertStringToInt(text3, Array.getLength(String.valueOf(text3.split(" "))) -> .....?????
```

Answer (score 2):

Если я все верно понял, то все довольно несложно:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Function<String,Integer> function = str->str.split(" ").length;
    String text = "We have to count words of this text";        
    convertStringToInt(text, function);
}
public static Integer convertStringToInt(String string, Function<String, Integer> function) {
    return function.apply(string);
}
```